# $watch not finding changes on property in array of objects on new item in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects like this...

```
[{ name: 'foo', price: 9.99, qty: 1 }]
```

The UI allows for new items to be added to this array. I'm trying to listen for those new items to be added AND for changes on the `qty` property of each item.

```
$scope.order = [];
$scope.totalItems = 0;
$scope.$watchCollection('order', function() {
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.order.reduce(function(memo, o) {
        return memo + o.qty;
    }, 0);
});

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.order.push({
        name: $scope.item.name,
        qty: 1,
        options: []
    });
};
```

As you can see from this... http://d.pr/v/MJzP The function fires when a new item is added, but NOT when the `qty` changes on that new item.

Comment: Can you quickly mockup a JSFiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should attach an `ngChange` to your quantity input box? Like this

```
<input ng-model="item.qty" ng-change="calculateTotal()" type="number"/>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function() {
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.order.reduce(function(memo, o) {
    return memo + o.qty;
  }, 0);
};
```

Then at the end of your add item function:

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
  // Your logic
  $scope.calculateTotal();
};
```

**EDIT:** After thinking about this more, the `ngChange` might automatically be invoked when the `addItem` function is called so calling it from `addItem` might not be entirely necessary

Comment: BAM. Thanks a ton. That's way nicer than having to use `$watchCollection` anyways!